# info.php in c:/apache/htdocs not giving information about php

Tags: php, apache

I am new to php. I tried running following code:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

when in web browser i type `localhost/info.php` it gives me same line of code instead of displaying all information about php

Comment: Is apache running? It seems like it's serving the `php` file rather than interpreting it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the PHP Interpreter is not associated to Apache. Download the appropriate version @ [PHP Homepage](https://secure.php.net/)

After downloading, extract to: C:\PHP\

Add the following lines to your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:\PHP\php7apache2_4.dll" 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:\PHP\php.ini"
```

Restart Apache then check your phpinfo() command.

If the above steps did not work, posting your Apache version will help us provide troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable php! Check the folder mods_enabled in the Apache directory to see if you find a file named php. I don't remember the extension but I think it's .so.

Also check apache error to see if you have any errors.